# How to interpret a long string into a csv format?

Tags: bash, export-to-csv

I have a `mytext.txt` file which has the following inside it:

```
2016-08-13 00:54:02,1471049642,62,28,16 2016-08-13 00:54:03,1471049643,62,28,20 2016-08-13 00:54:04,1471049644,62,28,18 2016-08-13 00:54:05,1471049645,62,28,18 2016-08-13 00:54:06,1471049646,62,28,19 2016-08-13 00:54:07,1471049647,62,28,17 2016-08-13 00:54:08,1471049648,62,28,19 2016-08-13 00:54:09,1471049649,62,28,16 2016-08-13 00:54:10,1471049650,62,28,19 2016-08-13 00:54:11,1471049651,62,28,18
```

I have tried to do a `while` loop with BASH :

```
while IFS="," read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
do 
   echo -e "f1:$f1 f2:$f2 f3:$f3 f4:$f4 f5:$f5"
done < mytext.txt
```

to get the following output:

```
2016-08-13 00:54:02,1471049642,62,28,16
2016-08-13 00:54:03,1471049643,62,28,20
2016-08-13 00:54:04,1471049644,62,28,18
2016-08-.....
```

but the output I get is:

```
f1:2016-08-13 00:54:02 f2:1471049642 f3:62 f4:28 f5:16 2016-08-13 00:54:03,1471049643,62,28,20  2016-08-13 00:54:04,1471049644,62,28,18 2016-08-....
```

Where `$f5` holds the rest of the read file.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this easily with `sed` by replacing space before date with newline:

```
sed -E $'s/ ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} )/\\\n\\1/g' mytext.txt
```

with gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} )/\n\1/g' mytext.txt
```

**Output:**

```
2016-08-13 00:54:02,1471049642,62,28,16
2016-08-13 00:54:03,1471049643,62,28,20
2016-08-13 00:54:04,1471049644,62,28,18
2016-08-13 00:54:05,1471049645,62,28,18
2016-08-13 00:54:06,1471049646,62,28,19
2016-08-13 00:54:07,1471049647,62,28,17
2016-08-13 00:54:08,1471049648,62,28,19
2016-08-13 00:54:09,1471049649,62,28,16
2016-08-13 00:54:10,1471049650,62,28,19
2016-08-13 00:54:11,1471049651,62,28,18
```

Comment: ideally I want to push this out to a csv file - that will later be processed by GNUPlot. **Q:**  How can I push this into `mycsvfile.csv`?

Comment: `s/ ([0-9-]{10} )/\n\1/g` would also work for this data set

Comment: @3kstc: You can redirect the output to a csv file: `sed -E 's/ ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} )/\n\1/g' mytext.txt > mycsvfile.csv`